# Spring-boot app

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

Как построить Spring-boot приложение, если мне нужно просто записать данные в БД которые вытянуты с Facebook, но ничего мне отображать не надо?

Если код необходим я добавлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто не используйте Spring MVC, раз вам не нужно показывать web-контент пользователю.

Напишите для работы с базой данных DAO-слой на JDBC или Spring Data, на ваш вкус, и сервис который будет что-то брать с Facebook и складывать в DAO.

Сервис вызывайте по расписанию через [Spring Tasks](http://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) или однократно при старте приложения, как вам нужно.

Comment: A JPA подойдет для таких целей? И если мне нужно на выход JSON массивы отдать? Это не послужит проблемой?

Comment: Можно и JPA, почему нет? "На выход" - это в БД?

Comment: ну у нас будет андроид приложение. Моя задача написать сервер который будет стягивать инфу с фейсбука и отдавать приложению в виде JSOn массивов

Comment: Тогда без веба не обойтись. JAX-RS в видe Jersey будет в самый раз.

Comment: понял) я просто уже психую то там бин не создался то тут бин не создался) не жизнь а одно разочарование

Answer (score 0):

**File > New Project > Spring Inizilizer > Next > Next > Next**

- Ставим галочки на Mysql (раздел SQL), Jpa, JDBC
- В файле **application.properties**  пишешь логин, пароль, хост базы

  **datasource.url**=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test

  **datasource.usernam**e=dbuser

  **datasource.passwor**d=dbpass
- Создаешь сущность сохраняемого объекта и сохраняешь.

http://spring-projects.ru/guides/relational-data-access/